# RHEL5/6/7 : If NM_CONTROLLED is not set what is the default value?

Tags: rhel, networkmanager, interface, defaults

If `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/eth0` does not include any NM_CONTROLLED setting on a RHEL-based distribution, what's the default behaviour?

Is there any difference in the default setting between RHEL5/6/7?

Comment: The question is apparently distribution specific but no linux distribution is specified.

Comment: edited question to specify RHEL-based distributions, as they are the most likely candidate here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually only NM_CONTROLLED="no" (or is it "false" ?) does anything.

Putting "yes" (or is it "true" ?) is the same as not having the line at all:
for network devices supported by NetworkManager it will manage them; for those unknown to NetworkManager it will ignore them anyway.

Comment: So the default is "yes" in simple words.